# Debugging GWT code running on an Android device

Tags: android, gwt, cordova

I have created an Android project in Eclipse. Then I added phoneGap support and created my assets/www folder.
 Then I have added GWT support to it and created a GWT module that pops up a button that says Hello when I click it. Then I configured my GWT compiler to dump it's out put in the assets/www folder of my project.
Now when I make a change in my GWT module,  I do a GWT compile and then start as Android application I can see my UI changes so everything looks ok.  Problem is I can't get it to hit any breakpoints I put in when in debug mode. Must be a port problem I'm guessing but any one know what I could check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think GWT breakpoints will work in a PhoneGap app. GWT running in Eclipse's debugger can use the breakpoints because the GWT app is running in an environment that Eclipse can pause the program execution and allow for inspection. Once you compile your GWT app and deploy it to an Android emulator I don't believe that GWT or Eclipse has that level of control anymore. It's probably best to find a way to use logging statements that will print to Logcat so you can debug that way.

Comment: Fair enough, That's what I was thinking but just wanted to put it out there